# What's the equivalent of a functor map across a vector in c++

Tags: c++

I'm normally a Haskell programmer doing some work in c++. What's the equivalent of a

```
fmap a -> (a->b) -> fmap b
```

for a c++ vector? Boost_foreach is close.

Comment: `std::transform`?   http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) is the closest thing to `fmap` for containers.

Example:

```
std::vector<int> src{/*...*/};
std::vector<std::string> dst;

std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), std::back_inserter(dst),
               [](int x){ return std::to_string(x); });
```